# "make" command throwing off syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: windows, makefile, cmake, gnu-make

I am new to building and compiling projects, so any help would be really appreciated. Also if somebody could guide me towards any good resources on similar topics, that would be great.

**The issue** -
For simple C++ header and source files - (Hello, World program), I am using Cmake to generate Unix makefiles on Windows OS, and then running make on the output. I have the GNU-make installed on my system. All commands were running fine until a couple of days ago, but now all of a sudden I am getting the following errors -
`` /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make -s -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all' make: *** [all] Error 1 ``

I have done no changes on my system to the C/C++ compilers. The only recent change I can remember is installing VSCode extensions for C#. I don't think that should affect this anyways. Could someone have any inkling as to where this error might be arising from? I am at a loss here! Looking for any possible support! Thanks.

Comment: It is confused by the space symbol in `Program Files` part of the path.

Comment: Thanks, @arrowd so much for pointing it out. I must have overlooked it because it was working without any issues until a few days ago. So I couldn't make out what had prompted such a change. Anyways, I reinstalled at a new location and added it to my environment variables, and it works like a charm again! :)